# About the eigenvalues of real symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Let $S$ be an $n×n$ symmetric real matrix, and for some $v≠0$, $\|Sv-αv\|<ε\|v\|$ ($α$ is a real number). Then how can we prove that $S$ has at least one eigenvalue $λ$ with $|λ-α|<ε$?
I am aware that the eigenvectors associated with different eigenvalues are orthogonal, but how can I apply this? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The eigenvectors in this case will form a basis. Thus, that particular vector $v$ can be decomposed as a linear combination of the orthogonal eigenvectors.

Comment: $Sv - \alpha v = \sum_i^n b_i (\lambda_i - \alpha) v_i$